# Do Americans drop the 'a' as in 'that's good time'?

Tags: american-english, articles

Do Americans tend to drop the indefinite article in spoken English? I'm under the impression that they do.

I've just watched a movie in which two guys were chatting about horse racing. One of them mentioned a certain horse's performance and the other replied with "that's good time".

Comment: We can drop the indefinite article in "that's good time" because *time* can be an uncountable noun in that sentence. We don't drop the indefinite article in, for example, "I had a good time" because *time* is countable in that sentence.

Comment: What @Peter Shor said.  But note that the ***a*** wasn’t *dropped*.  Rather it wasn’t ever there to begin with.

Comment: @Jim: I'm with Peter on this one. Same as *That's [an] unhealthy food* or *Last year we had [a] below-average rainfall*, which to my BrE ear sound syntactically credible with or without the article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think of the two differently.  In the same way that “He makes good money” is fundamentally different than “he makes a good salary”.  I can’t add an ’a’:  “he makes a good money”   So even though it works with or without- thus switching between the two meanings, if the first was meant, the ’a’ wasn’t dropped.

Comment: @Jim: I don't see any difference in *meaning* as such in OP's exact context, though you might be able to differentiate, for example, *That's [a] good play!* With the article that would have to refer to a single coherent set of actions within a game, of relatively short duration in total (where *without* the article it might feasibly even refer to an entire lengthy game, from start to finish). But to my mind there's room for a *lot* of flexibility as regards the exact syntax role of ***X*** in statements of the general form *That's X* (X=noun, adjective, whatever).

Comment: ...consider *Does he really earn £5000 a week? Now that's what I call [a] high income!* With or without the article ("noun" or "adjective", if you will), both versions seem perfectly idiomatic to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree, they are both idiomatic and are practically interchangeable but one comments on a particular income as being high and the other on that income as being in the upper echelons.  I guess it’s a very subtle distinction.

Answer (score 5):

No. There are a number of different idiomatic uses of *time* (most of them with *good time*) that do not need an article. They usually have a meaning of either promptness or speed.

In the context of a horse *that's good time* means that the horse has run the course at a good speed - i.e. has taken a good (short) time to run the course.

Other related phrases are:

> *in good time* = "early enough"
>
> *make good time* = (arrive) earlier than might have been expected.